# Unable to reliably connect Pi HDMI to Motorola Atrix Lapdock

Tags: hdmi

I have a Motorola Atrix Lapdock connected to my Raspberry Pi using the instructions provided on various web sites including http://rpidock.blogspot.com/.

The HDMI output initially displays on the Lapdock, but if I close the Lapdock and reopen it the video will not display.  I find that sometimes rebooting the Pi or completely disconnecting the Lapdock (both USB and HDMI connections) will cause the display to work again.

I've even tried setting "hdmi_safe=1" to get the display to consistently work after closing and reopening the Lapdock or rebooting the Pi.

Could I just have a flaky Lapdock?  I guess that I need to connect the Lapdock to a different HDMI source to see it behaves opening and closing the Lapdock.

Are there any other config.txt commands that I should try?

Are there any command line commands that I can run while SSH'ed into my Pi to check the status of the HDMI output?

---

### Update (2013-07-16):

**Can anyone with a working Lapdock perform the `tvservice -d edit.out` command parsing the output using `edidparser edid.out` posting your results here for comparison?**

Using the `tvservice -d edid.out`command I was able to dump the [EDID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_display_identification_data) information from my Lapdoc, here is what that was returned:

```
johnma@raspberrypi:~$ edidparser edid.out
Enabling fuzzy format match...
Parsing d.out...
HDMI:EDID version 1.3, 1 extensions, screen size 26x14 cm
HDMI:EDID features - videodef 0x80 !standby !suspend !active off; colour encoding:RGB444|YCbCr422; sRGB is not default colourspace; preferred format is native; does not support GTF
HDMI:EDID found monitor S/N descriptor tag 0xff
HDMI:EDID found monitor range descriptor tag 0xfd
HDMI:EDID monitor range offsets: V min=0, V max=0, H min=0, H max=0
HDMI:EDID monitor range: vertical is 50-75 Hz, horizontal is 30-85 kHz, max pixel clock is 150 MHz
HDMI:EDID monitor range does not support GTF
HDMI:EDID found monitor name descriptor tag 0xfc
HDMI:EDID monitor name is MotoAttach
HDMI:EDID found preferred DMT detail timing format: 1366x768p @ 60 Hz (86)
HDMI:EDID established timing I/II bytes are 00 00 00
HDMI:EDID standard timings block x 8: 0x0101 0101 0101 0101 0101 0101 0101 0101
HDMI:EDID parsing v3 CEA extension 0
HDMI:EDID monitor support - underscan IT formats:no, basic audio:yes, yuv444:yes, yuv422:yes, #native DTD:1
HDMI:EDID found DMT detail timing format: 1366x768p @ 60 Hz (86)
HDMI:EDID failed to find a matching detail format for 0x720p hfp:110 hs:40 hbp:-134 vfp:5 vs:5 vbp:20 pixel clock:0 MHz
HDMI:EDID calculated refresh rate is 0 Hz
HDMI:EDID guessing the format to be 0x720p @24 Hz
HDMI:EDID found unknown detail timing format: 0x720p hfp:110 hs:40 hbp:-134 vfp:5 vs:5 vbp:20 pixel clock:0 MHz
HDMI:EDID failed to find a matching detail format for 0x1080i hfp:88 hs:44 hbp:-116 vfp:2 vs:5 vbp:16 pixel clock:0 MHz
HDMI:EDID calculated refresh rate is 0 Hz
HDMI:EDID guessing the format to be 0x1080i @24 Hz
HDMI:EDID found unknown detail timing format: 0x1080i hfp:88 hs:44 hbp:-116 vfp:2 vs:5 vbp:16 pixel clock:0 MHz
HDMI:EDID found CEA format: code 1, 640x480p @ 60Hz
HDMI:EDID found CEA format: code 3, 720x480p @ 60Hz
HDMI:EDID found CEA format: code 18, 720x576p @ 50Hz
HDMI:EDID found audio format 2 channels PCM, sample rate: 32|44|48|96|192 kHz, sample size: 16|20|24 bits
HDMI:EDID found HDMI VSDB length 5
HDMI:EDID HDMI VSDB has physical address 1.0.0.0
HDMI:EDID HDMI VSDB has no extension fields
HDMI:EDID adding mandatory support for DMT (4) 640x480p @ 60Hz
HDMI:EDID adding mandatory support for CEA (2) 720x480p @ 60Hz
HDMI:EDID adding mandatory support for CEA (17) 720x576p @ 50Hz
HDMI:EDID filtering formats with pixel clock > 162 MHz or h. blanking > 1023
HDMI:EDID best score mode initialised to DMT (4) 640x480p @ 60 Hz with pixel clock 25 MHz (score 0)
HDMI:EDID best score mode is now CEA (1) 640x480p @ 60 Hz with pixel clock 25 MHz (score 43432)
HDMI:EDID best score mode is now CEA (2) 720x480p @ 60 Hz with pixel clock 27 MHz (score 45736)
HDMI:EDID CEA mode (3) 720x480p @ 60 Hz with pixel clock 27 MHz has a score of 45736
HDMI:EDID DMT mode (4) 640x480p @ 60 Hz with pixel clock 25 MHz has a score of 36864
HDMI:EDID CEA mode (17) 720x576p @ 50 Hz with pixel clock 27 MHz has a score of 45736
HDMI:EDID CEA mode (18) 720x576p @ 50 Hz with pixel clock 27 MHz has a score of 45736
HDMI:EDID best score mode is now DMT (86) 1366x768p @ 60 Hz with pixel clock 72 MHz (score 5188835)
HDMI:EDID preferred mode remained as DMT (86) 1366x768p @ 60 Hz with pixel clock 72 MHz
HDMI:EDID has HDMI support and audio support
edid_parser exited with code 0
```

---

### Update (2013-07-28):

Partial success! I am able to get the display to work consistently if I execute the following commands:

```
tvservice -e "DMT 4"
```

That commands sets the following profile:

```
tvservice -s 
state 0x12001a [HDMI DMT (4) RGB full 4:3], 640x480 @ 60Hz, progressive
```

Then to get the display to appear I need to execute the following frame buffer command:

```
fbset 640x480-60

fbset --show

mode "640x480-60"
    # D: 25.175 MHz, H: 31.469 kHz, V: 59.940 Hz
    geometry 640 480 640 480 8
    timings 39722 48 16 33 10 96 2
    accel true
    rgba 8/0,8/0,8/0,0/0
endmode
```

I am, however, unable to get the display to work consistently at its native resolution of 1366x768. My /etc/fb.modes file does not contain any entry for 1366x768.

**Can someone with a working Atrix lapdock post the output of the following command:**

```
fbset --show
```

Thank you!

---

### Update (2013-07-30):

**More success!**

I am able to reliably get the Lapdock to display HDMI video using 1280x720 resolution.  I achieve this using the following parameters in my `/boot/config.txt` file:

```
# Force DMT mode 85 HDMI
hdmi_group=2
hdmi_mode=85
hdmi_drive=2

# Ignore the devices EDID information
hdmi_ignore_edid=0xa5000080
```

`tvservice -s` returns:

```
state 0x12001a [HDMI DMT (85) RGB full 16:9], 1280x720 @ 60Hz, progressive
```

`fbset --show` returns:

```
mode "1280x720"
    geometry 1280 720 1280 720 16
    timings 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
    rgba 5/11,6/5,5/0,0/16
endmode
```

I get no video display when using DMT mode (86) 1366x768 @ 60Hz which is supposed to be the native size of the display.

Could this be a problem with my HDMI cable connection?  Could my exising HDMI cable and HDMI micro adapter have some bandwidth limitation that is preventing 1366x768 resolution from being displayed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The micro female HDMI to micro male HDMI cable that I was using was the root cause of my problem.
[image]

When using that cable I could only achieve a maximum resolution of 1280x720.

Using only this adapter I am able to use the native resolution of the lapdock which is 1366x768.  I am also able to reliably get a video display after closing and reopening the lapdock.

[image]

I also updated my firmware to version `#518 PREEMPT Fri Aug 2 11:39:53 BST 2013 armv6l`.

Comment: This post has helped me a lot. Thx. What precisely was wrong with the wiring of the cable? Have you dissected it to find out. Was it a missing GND?

Answer (score 3):

I got my lapdock (100 model) to work in mode 81 regardless of whether I used a micro-hdmi coupler with cable or just an adaptor.

```
## 1366x768 @ 60Hz ##
hdmi_force_hotplug=1
hdmi_group=2
hdmi_mode=81
```

I have yet to get it working in 720p mode, which is apparently the only way to get audio working over HDMI (according to this page - https://motorola-global-portal.custhelp.com/app/answers/prod_answer_detail/a_id/71856/p/7980,8212/action/auth)

For comparison, here is my EDID parser output ...

```
Enabling fuzzy format match...
Parsing edid.dat2...
HDMI:EDID version 1.3, 1 extensions, screen size 22x13 cm
HDMI:EDID features - videodef 0x80 standby suspend active off; colour encoding:RGB444|YCbCr422; sRGB is not default colourspace; preferred format is native; does not support GTF
HDMI:EDID found monitor S/N descriptor tag 0xff
HDMI:EDID found monitor name descriptor tag 0xfc
HDMI:EDID monitor name is MotoLD2S_____þ
HDMI:EDID does not yet know monitor vertical range, setting to default 24 to 120Hz
HDMI:EDID failed to find a matching detail format for 1366x768p hfp:59 hs:39 hbp:96 vfp:5 vs:9 vbp:24 pixel clock:72 MHz
HDMI:EDID calculated refresh rate is 57 Hz
HDMI:EDID guessing the format to be 1366x768p @60 Hz
HDMI:EDID found preferred DMT detail timing format: 1366x768p @ 60 Hz (81)
HDMI:EDID failed to find a matching detail format for 1366x768p hfp:59 hs:39 hbp:96 vfp:5 vs:9 vbp:24 pixel clock:75 MHz
HDMI:EDID calculated refresh rate is 60 Hz
HDMI:EDID guessing the format to be 1366x768p @60 Hz
HDMI:EDID found DMT detail timing format: 1366x768p @ 60 Hz (81)
HDMI:EDID established timing I/II bytes are 00 00 00
HDMI:EDID standard timings block x 8: 0x0101 0101 0101 0101 0101 0101 0101 0101 
HDMI:EDID parsing v3 CEA extension 0
HDMI:EDID monitor support - underscan IT formats:no, basic audio:yes, yuv444:yes, yuv422:yes, #native DTD:0
HDMI:EDID failed to find a matching detail format for 1366x768p hfp:59 hs:39 hbp:96 vfp:5 vs:9 vbp:24 pixel clock:72 MHz
HDMI:EDID calculated refresh rate is 57 Hz
HDMI:EDID guessing the format to be 1366x768p @60 Hz
HDMI:EDID found DMT detail timing format: 1366x768p @ 60 Hz (81)
HDMI:EDID failed to find a matching detail format for 1366x768p hfp:59 hs:39 hbp:96 vfp:5 vs:9 vbp:24 pixel clock:75 MHz
HDMI:EDID calculated refresh rate is 60 Hz
HDMI:EDID guessing the format to be 1366x768p @60 Hz
HDMI:EDID found DMT detail timing format: 1366x768p @ 60 Hz (81)
HDMI:EDID failed to find a matching detail format for 1366x768p hfp:59 hs:39 hbp:96 vfp:5 vs:9 vbp:24 pixel clock:72 MHz
HDMI:EDID calculated refresh rate is 57 Hz
HDMI:EDID guessing the format to be 1366x768p @60 Hz
HDMI:EDID found DMT detail timing format: 1366x768p @ 60 Hz (81)
HDMI:EDID failed to find a matching detail format for 1366x768p hfp:59 hs:39 hbp:96 vfp:5 vs:9 vbp:24 pixel clock:72 MHz
HDMI:EDID calculated refresh rate is 57 Hz
HDMI:EDID guessing the format to be 1366x768p @60 Hz
HDMI:EDID found DMT detail timing format: 1366x768p @ 60 Hz (81)
HDMI:EDID failed to find a matching detail format for 1366x768p hfp:59 hs:39 hbp:96 vfp:5 vs:9 vbp:24 pixel clock:72 MHz
HDMI:EDID calculated refresh rate is 57 Hz
HDMI:EDID guessing the format to be 1366x768p @60 Hz
HDMI:EDID found DMT detail timing format: 1366x768p @ 60 Hz (81)
HDMI:EDID found CEA format: code 2, 720x480p @ 60Hz 
HDMI:EDID found audio format 2 channels PCM, sample rate: 44 kHz, sample size: 16 bits
HDMI:EDID found HDMI VSDB length 5
HDMI:EDID HDMI VSDB has physical address 1.0.0.0
HDMI:EDID HDMI VSDB has no extension fields
HDMI:EDID adding mandatory support for DMT (4) 640x480p @ 60Hz
HDMI:EDID adding mandatory support for CEA (1) 640x480p @ 60Hz
HDMI:EDID adding mandatory support for CEA (3) 720x480p @ 60Hz
HDMI:EDID filtering formats with pixel clock > 162 MHz or h. blanking > 1023
HDMI:EDID best score mode initialised to DMT (4) 640x480p @ 60 Hz with pixel clock 25 MHz (score 0)
HDMI:EDID best score mode is now CEA (1) 640x480p @ 60 Hz with pixel clock 25 MHz (score 43432)
HDMI:EDID best score mode is now CEA (2) 720x480p @ 60 Hz with pixel clock 27 MHz (score 45736)
HDMI:EDID CEA mode (3) 720x480p @ 60 Hz with pixel clock 27 MHz has a score of 45736
HDMI:EDID DMT mode (4) 640x480p @ 60 Hz with pixel clock 25 MHz has a score of 36864
HDMI:EDID best score mode is now DMT (81) 1366x768p @ 60 Hz with pixel clock 85 MHz (score 5188835)
HDMI:EDID preferred mode remained as DMT (81) 1366x768p @ 60 Hz with pixel clock 85 MHz
HDMI:EDID has HDMI support and audio support
edid_parser exited with code 0
```